# Can I change my Macro to exclude specified text in files?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have my macro setup and its working, both the hyperlinking portion and the file listing portions i have made, however they are picking up files I cant seem to find in my files

(Ie: Run Sheets\~$RUNSHEET - # 1-H.xlsx)

When I go to the file directly and turn on the folder settings to view hidden and what-knot, the files aren't there also they seem to be temp files left over from when my files were worked.

is there anyway I can change my code to exclude "~$" files?

here is my code, the first one is the directory lister:

```
Sub ListFilesAndSubfolders()

  Dim FSO As Object
  Dim rsFSO As Object
  Dim baseFolder As Object
  Dim file As Object
  Dim folder As Object
  Dim row As Integer
  Dim name As String

  'Get the current folder
  Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  Set baseFolder = FSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)
  Set FSO = Nothing

  'Get the row at which to insert
  row = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row + 1

  'Create the recordset for sorting
  Set rsFSO = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  With rsFSO.Fields
    .Append "Name", 200, 200
    .Append "Type", 200, 200
  End With
  rsFSO.Open

  ' Traverse the entire folder tree
  TraverseFolderTree baseFolder, baseFolder, rsFSO
  Set baseFolder = Nothing

  'Sort by type and name
  rsFSO.Sort = "Type ASC, Name ASC "
  rsFSO.MoveFirst

  'Populate the first column of the sheet
  While Not rsFSO.EOF
    name = rsFSO("Name").value
    If (name <> ThisWorkbook.name) Then
      Cells(row, 1).Formula = name
      row = row + 1
    End If
    rsFSO.MoveNext
  Wend

  'Close the recordset
  rsFSO.Close
  Set rsFSO = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub TraverseFolderTree(ByVal parent As Object, ByVal node As Object, ByRef rs As Object)

  'List all files
  For Each file In node.Files

    Dim name As String
    name = Mid(file.Path, Len(parent.Path) + 2)

    rs.AddNew
    rs("Name") = name
    rs("Type") = "FILE"
    rs.Update
  Next

  'List all folders
  For Each folder In node.SubFolders
    TraverseFolderTree parent, folder, rs
  Next

End Sub
```

And the second one is the hyperlinker code:

```
Sub hyperlinker()

  Dim MOG As Object
  Dim rsMOG As Object
  Dim PrimeF As Object
  Dim Bit As Object
  Dim Foder As Object
  Dim Linger As Integer
  Dim Enigma As String
  Dim way As String


  'Get the current folder
  Set MOG = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  Set PrimeF = MOG.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)
  Set MOG = Nothing

  'Get the row at which to insert
   Linger = Range("U65536").End(xlUp).row + 1

  'Create the recordset for sorting
  Set rsMOG = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  With rsMOG.Fields
    .Append "Way", 200, 200
    .Append "Enigma", 200, 200
    .Append "Bit", 200, 200
  End With
  rsMOG.Open

  ' Traverse the entire folder tree
  TraverseFolderTree PrimeF, PrimeF, rsMOG
  Set PrimeF = Nothing

  'Sort by type and name
  rsMOG.Sort = "Bit ASC, Enigma ASC "
  rsMOG.MoveFirst

  'Populate the first column of the sheet
   While Not rsMOG.EOF
    Enigma = rsMOG("Enigma").value
    way = rsMOG("Way").value
    If (Enigma <> ThisWorkbook.name) Then
      ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(Linger, 21), Address:=way, TextToDisplay:=Enigma
      Linger = Linger + 1
    End If
    rsMOG.MoveNext
  Wend

  'Close the recordset
  rsMOG.Close
  Set rsMOG = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub TraverseFolderTree(ByVal parent As Object, ByVal node As Object, ByRef rs As Object)

  'List all files
  For Each Bit In node.Files

    Dim Enigma As String
    Enigma = Mid(Bit.Path, Len(parent.Path) + 2)

    Dim way As String
    way = Mid(Bit.Path, Len(parent.Path) + 2)

    rs.AddNew
    rs("Way") = way
    rs("Enigma") = Enigma
    rs("Bit") = "Bit"
    rs.Update
  Next

  'List all folders
  For Each Foder In node.SubFolders
    TraverseFolderTree parent, Foder, rs
  Next

End Sub
```

i need to eliminate these additional "~$" data from my lists, some lists can be several hundred files so nit picking the data would be pretty time consuming.

any ideas?

Another tip, is I could just eliminate the .xlsx extensions since all of my data does have excel documents in them?

Answer (score 0):

In the directory lister make these changes:

```
'List all files
  For Each file In node.Files
    if InStr(file.Path, "~$") > 0 then
      Dim name As String
      name = Mid(file.Path, Len(parent.Path) + 2)

      rs.AddNew
      rs("Name") = name
      rs("Type") = "FILE"
      rs.Update
    end if
  Next
```

---

In the hyperlinker code change this:

```
  For Each Bit In node.Files
    if InStr(file.Path, "~$") > 0 then
      Dim Enigma As String
      Enigma = Mid(Bit.Path, Len(parent.Path) + 2)

      Dim way As String
      way = Mid(Bit.Path, Len(parent.Path) + 2)

      rs.AddNew
      rs("Way") = way
      rs("Enigma") = Enigma
      rs("Bit") = "Bit"
      rs.Update
    End If
  Next
```

Comment: did the first part with inserting the `IF InStr(file.path, "~$") > 0 then` and the `end if` 
however not sure what to do with the second part you have separate from the first code.

however right now im getting an "Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record."

Comment: Ignore the second code, I was just trying to point out what was different and what it was doing.  I edited the post.

Comment: Okay, I think I see it.  I directed you to update the first part of the code for the directory lister but the hyperlink code is still searching all files.  I'll edit my post in a bit.